# What is the proper way to open an action in a new site?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

What is the proper way to open an action in a new site(without main content) but with the top and site menu?

Atm I use typoscript to stick my content at the bottom of the header and delete tt_content.

Link:

```
<f:link.action action="project" arguments="{id: '{item._id}'}" pageType="85720">
    cake
</f:link.action>
```

Typoscript:

```
stdPage = PAGE
stdPage < page
stdPage {
    typeNum = 85720
}

[globalVar = GP:type = 85720]
    lib.sectionheader.400 < tt_content.list.20.myext_myextpi
    tt_content >
[global]
```

Comment: where's the php question?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "without main content". To open the action on another page, use the pageUid="123" attribute of the f:link.action viewhelper. On the other side, just add the content you want.

Comment: Do you need the target action on the same page? If not you could just go for `<f:link.action pageUid="{settings.projectPage}" action="project" …>`. And on the page you define in `plugin.tx_myext.settings.projectPage` you just add your plugin. And maybe remove everything else you don‘t want via TS.

Comment: @PaulBeck I want to link to a page that doesn't exist. Where my extension fills the whole tt_content. Or if this isn't possible I search a nicer way to show only my action output after clicking at my link.

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for smth like this.

First create a general prototypeAjaxPage that will be used in all new controller/action that needs only to show content from extension:

```
prototypeAjaxPage = PAGE
prototypeAjaxPage {
   config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/html
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
   }
}
```

Then create own pagetype that inherits the general and define what controler and action you want to run there.

```
myExtContent < prototypeAjaxPage
myExtContent {
  typeNum = 85720

  10 = USER
  10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = YourVendor
    extensionName = ExtensionName
    pluginName = PluginName
    switchableControllerActions {
        MyControler {
            1 = myAction
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need some additional content to be put with output of extension (like "top menu" you are reffering to) then you can include it as partial in fluid template. If you need all css/js then disable config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1